# ObservableCollection items - modify property of individual items if a flag is set

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a data grid, and observable collection is bound to it:

```
private ObservableCollection<RequestParameter> _parameters = new ObservableCollection<RequestParameter>();

    public ObservableCollection<RequestParameter> Parameters
    {
        get { return _parameters; }
        set { Set(ref _parameters, value); }
    }

    private bool _isPostRequest;
    public bool IsPostRequest
    {
        get { return _isPostRequest; }
        set { Set(ref _isPostRequest, value); }
    }
```

And the model:

```
public class RequestParameter
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsPostParameter { get; set; }
}
```

So on the UI, I have a checkbox and a datagrid

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column" RowHeaderWidth="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}" CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" MinHeight="140">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}" Width="*"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="*"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
  <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsChecked="{Binding IsPostRequest}"/>
```

So if the check box is clicked, `IsPostParameter` of all items in the collection should be set to `True`.

The only way I can think of is in the getter or the setter of the `Parameters` field, check for `IsPostRequest` property of the viewmodel, and if it is, run through all parameters and set the flag.
Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: you need to use bool to checked converter http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can check it over IsPostRequest setter property

```
    private bool _isPostRequest;
    public bool IsPostRequest
    {
        get { return _isPostRequest; }
        set
        {
            _isPostRequest = value;
            Parameters.ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsPostParameter = value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsPostRequest");
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a Command to your view model and set the CheckBox command property to that command. And pass IsChecked as parameter:  `CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Mode=OneWay}`
Then in your command iterate over your collection items and set your field to the appropriate value.